# Random forest getting 100% score since feature selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have been working on a dataset. I have followed this process to predict churn:

1) encoded and standardised data
2) run random forest
3) Got a model score of 0.63
4) Analysed feature importances
5) ran model for reduced feature set
6) got a model score of 1.0 in the revised model

I am not sure why the score is suddenly 100%. I've checked feature importances again & there are none that have a 100% contribution to the prediction. I have also made sure that I've used the test train split function, so I shouldn't have test and training data leaking.

If anyone can help me, that would be amazing as I am really stuck!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# # The Scenario

# From https://www.kaggle.com/abhinav89/telecom-customer/version/1.
# 
# This data set consists of 100 variables and approx 100 thousand records. This data set contains different variables explaining the attributes of telecom industry and various factors considered important while dealing with customers of telecom industry. The target variable here is churn which explains whether the customer will churn or not. We can use this data set to predict the customers who would churn or who wouldn't churn depending on various variables available.

# # Import data

# In[1]:


import pandas as pd
path = "churn.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=',', header='infer')
df.head()


# # Generate the X (features) and y (target) dataframes

# In[2]:


x=  df[[
 'rev_Mean',
 'mou_Mean',
 'totmrc_Mean',
 'da_Mean',
 'ovrmou_Mean',
 'ovrrev_Mean',
 'vceovr_Mean',
 'datovr_Mean',
 'roam_Mean',
 'change_mou',
 'change_rev',
 'drop_vce_Mean',
 'drop_dat_Mean',
 'blck_vce_Mean',
 'blck_dat_Mean',
 'unan_vce_Mean',
 'unan_dat_Mean',
 'plcd_vce_Mean',
 'plcd_dat_Mean',
 'recv_vce_Mean',
 'recv_sms_Mean',
 'comp_vce_Mean',
 'comp_dat_Mean',
 'custcare_Mean',
 'ccrndmou_Mean',
 'cc_mou_Mean',
 'inonemin_Mean',
 'threeway_Mean',
 'mou_cvce_Mean',
 'mou_cdat_Mean',
 'mou_rvce_Mean',
 'owylis_vce_Mean',
 'mouowylisv_Mean',
 'iwylis_vce_Mean',
 'mouiwylisv_Mean',
 'peak_vce_Mean',
 'peak_dat_Mean',
 'mou_peav_Mean',
 'mou_pead_Mean',
 'opk_vce_Mean',
 'opk_dat_Mean',
 'mou_opkv_Mean',
 'mou_opkd_Mean',
 'drop_blk_Mean',
 'attempt_Mean',
 'complete_Mean',
 'callfwdv_Mean',
 'callwait_Mean',
 'months',
 'uniqsubs',
 'actvsubs',
 'new_cell',
 'crclscod',
 'asl_flag',
 'totcalls',
 'totmou',
 'totrev',
 'adjrev',
 'adjmou',
 'adjqty',
 'avgrev',
 'avgmou',
 'avgqty',
 'avg3mou',
 'avg3qty',
 'avg3rev',
 'avg6mou',
 'avg6qty',
 'avg6rev',
 'prizm_social_one',
 'area',
 'dualband',
 'refurb_new',
 'hnd_price',
 'phones',
 'models',
 'hnd_webcap',
 'truck',
 'rv',
 'ownrent',
 'lor',
 'dwlltype',
 'marital',
 'adults',
 'infobase',
 'income',
 'numbcars',
 'HHstatin',
 'dwllsize',
 'forgntvl',
 'ethnic',
 'kid0_2',
 'kid3_5',
 'kid6_10',
 'kid11_15',
 'kid16_17',
 'creditcd',
 'eqpdays',
 'Customer_ID'
       ]]


y =  df[['churn']]

#check columns in new df
list(x)


# In[3]:


#show unique values in the dataframe column
df.churn.unique()


# # Standardize & encode data
# 
# When we’re getting our data ready for our machine learning models, it’s important to consider scaling and encoding.
# 
# Scaling is a method used to standardise the range of data. This is important as if one field stores age (between 18 and 90) and another stores salary (between 10,000 and 200,000), the machine learning algorithm might bias its results towards the larger numbers, as it may assume they’re more important. SciKitLearn state that “If a feature has a variance that is orders of magnitude larger that others, it might dominate the objective function and make the estimator unable to learn from other features correctly as expected.”
# 
# Using this SciKitLearn library, we can convert each feature to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of 1; removing the potential bias in the model.
# 
# For some models, this is an absolute requirement, as certain algorithms expect that your data is normally distributed and centre around zero.
# 
# Encoding is simple – machine learning algorithms can only accept numerical features. If you have input variables of Male & Female, we can encode them to be 0 or 1 so that they can be used in the machine learning model

# In[4]:


from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
import numpy as np

#encoding with get_dummies
x = pd.get_dummies( x )

#fill in NA values with zeros
x = x.fillna(0)

#standardize the scale
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

#convert dataframes to numpy arrays
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)


# # Split data (75% training & 25% testing)

# In[5]:


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)


# # Train the model (fit) on the training data


# In[15]:


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)

model.fit(train_features, train_labels.ravel())


# In[16]:


predictions = model.predict(test_features)


# In[17]:


model.score(train_features, train_labels)


# In[18]:


model.score(test_features, test_labels)


# # Can we remove some features?
#  - Reduces Overfitting
#  - Improves Accuracy
#  - Reduces Training Time

# In[19]:


importance = model.feature_importances_
importances = pd.DataFrame(importance)

dictionary = dict(zip(df.columns, model.feature_importances_))


# In[20]:


feature_matrix = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index=[0])
featurex = feature_matrix.T
featurex.columns = ['meas']


# In[21]:


#Check the score for every column in the DF
sorted = featurex.sort_values(by=['meas'], ascending=False)
with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", 10000): 
    print(sorted)


# In[22]:


#create a new DF with only scores above a certain threshold
df_limited = df[['models',
'change_mou',
'hnd_webcap',
'churn',
'mou_Mean',
'change_rev',
'asl_flag',
'crclscod',
'adjmou',
'totrev',
'adjrev',
'rev_Mean',
'actvsubs',
'totmou',
'new_cell',
'totcalls',
'adjqty',
'mou_cvce_Mean',
'avgrev',
'avgqty',
'mou_opkv_Mean',
'mou_peav_Mean',
'avg3mou',
'mouowylisv_Mean',
'totmrc_Mean',
'mou_rvce_Mean',
'peak_vce_Mean',
'opk_vce_Mean',
'unan_vce_Mean',
'avg3qty',
'avgmou',
'recv_vce_Mean',
'owylis_vce_Mean',
'plcd_vce_Mean',
'attempt_Mean',
'complete_Mean',
'comp_vce_Mean',
'inonemin_Mean',
'drop_blk_Mean',
'mouiwylisv_Mean',
'drop_vce_Mean',
'ovrrev_Mean',
'ovrmou_Mean',
'iwylis_vce_Mean',
'blck_vce_Mean',
'avg3rev',
'vceovr_Mean',
'area']]


# In[23]:


#encoding with get_dummies
x2 = pd.get_dummies( df_limited )

#fill in NA values with zeros
x2 = x2.fillna(0)

#standardize the scale
x2 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x2)

#convert dataframes to numpy arrays
x2 = np.array(x2)


# In[24]:


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(x2, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)


# In[25]:


model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
model.fit(train_features, train_labels.ravel())


# In[26]:


predictions = model.predict(test_features)


# In[27]:


model.score(train_features, train_labels)


# In[28]:


model.score(test_features, test_labels)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `churn` in your x2 variable i.e. your second training dataset. The model is basically memorizing the result itself to predict the result.

The reason you dont have 100% feature importance for any feature is because you are doing one hot encoding on the dataset, so the churn variable gets divided into multiple columns.

`x2.drop('churn',1, inplace=True)`

This will solve your problem

Comment: Ahh thank you so much, I was being really stupid :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop churn from your training set. Because you kept it in, and that is what you are trying to predict, you have data leakage. Before you split train and test, do this:

```
x2.drop(columns=['churn'], inplace=True)
```

Please accept if this helps.

Comment: Overfitting is arguably not the correct term here

Comment: If churn is a feature, and the output depends entirely on churn, then is the algorithm not solely or disproportionately dependant on a portion of the dataset (churn) and therefore overfit?

Comment: Overfitting (practical) definition: training error continues going down, while validation error starts going up. What we have here is actually data *leakage* (we have included the target as a feature), which has nothing to do with overfitting (the model will continue giving perfect results in future unseen data, as long as the churn remains among the features)...

Comment: You're right. Data leakage would be a more appropriate term. Thank you, I will edit my answer.

Comment: You are very welcome